# Setting up the connection for a site using DreamWeaver and wampp 5: HTTP error 404

Tags: php, wamp

I use DreamWeaver to develop a website but when I tried to connect to it with Wampp 5, it displays `HTTP error 404`. I have checked the configuration and nothing seems to be wrong. I don't know what I am missing. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `error.log` file to see where in the filesystem the request ended up. It's most likely a problem in the `DocumentRoot` setting.